# Merge multiple csv columns into one while repeating the header

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am trying to merge multiple columns within a csv into a single column with each original column's header being repeated as shown below.

```
userA   userB
A1  B1
A2  B2
A2  B3
A2  B4
```

Into this:

```
userA   A1
userA   A2
userA   A3
userA   A4
userB   B1
userB   B2
userB   B3
userB   B4
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this. I do have some experience in pandas but I'm currently at a loss.

UPDATE: I found how to merge the columns

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t')
df = df.combine_first(pd.Series(df.values.ravel('F')).to_frame('merged'))
```

FINAL UPDATE: Solved using melt()

```
df = pd.melt(df)
```

Comment: With a dataframe of just those two columns, you could do `df.stack().reset_index(level=1)`

Comment: @cmaher This is great but the entries are not ordered properly. It's now alternating between userA and userB. Got an idea how to produce the above order?

Comment: That's not what your output in your question indicates. Can you update the expected output your question first?

Comment: Good work finding a solution, can you post that as the answer and accept it so we can close this question?

Comment: @cmaher I solved it! Your first comment was all I needed. I then used:  df.sort_values(by=[0]) to sort properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can using `melt`

```
df.melt()
Out[702]: 
  variable value
0    userA    A1
1    userA    A2
2    userA    A2
3    userA    A2
4    userB    B1
5    userB    B2
6    userB    B3
7    userB    B4
```

Comment: df=pd.melt(df) is exactly what I needed! Nothing more is required. Thank you.

Comment: @testac1234 yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

### construct with `ravel` and `repeat`

```
pd.Series(df.values.ravel(), df.columns.repeat(len(df)))

userA    A1
userA    B1
userA    A2
userA    B2
userB    A2
userB    B3
userB    A2
userB    B4
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved first using:

> With a dataframe of just those two columns, you could do
>   df.stack().reset_index(level=1) – cmaher

Following by a simple sort to order properly:

```
df.sort_values(by=[0])
```

See pd.melt(df) above for better answer.